# Migrating from PDO using SQLite to clean new install using MySQL

Tags: database, mysql, installation, migration

I've been using PDO plugin for wordpress and SQLite database. It does not work as expected so I want to use MySQL database, but without PDO for Wordpress since I cannot trust that plugin anymore, It has not been updated for more than 2 years.

So, this is what i did:

1. Exported SQLite database to sql file
2. Made necessary changes in syntax http://www.maxkpage.com/blog/free-sqlite-to-mysql-converter-super-easy/
3. Installed new Wordpress with new MySQL database
4. Copied old Wp-content folder and replaced the new one
5. Imported old data by copying all "INSERT INTO ...." form old into new tables, which I emptied first

Now, here comes the problem. Everything works fine, I can see the posts on website, but when I populate wp_users or wp_usermeta or wp_options with old data I get "You don't have sufficient permissions" message when I log into dashboard. Not wrong username or password, but when I log in I just see that message and the website becomes white blank.

Where is the problem and how can I fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is wrong.
The tutorial says to remove all double quotes " and replace them with spaces or backticks `, but some values in the mentioned tables have double quotes around them. This one for example:

```
INSERT INTO "wp_usermeta" VALUES(14,1,'wp_capabilities','a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');
```

So replacing that with backticks causes malfunction.

Replace only double quotes around table names "wp_usermeta" -> wp_usermeta